# JavaScript Validation to control issuing quantity in Codigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a simple code to issue fuel items like diesel. Then I need to apply javascript validation to control issuig quantity vs available quantity. Code as follows :

## Controller

```
$this->data['fuelItem'] = $this->Fuel_model->getFuelItem($id);

$avqty = filter_var($this->input->post('avqty'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
            if($amount > $avqty) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Issuing Quantity should be less than the available balance');
                redirect(base_url());
            } else {............
```

## Model

```
public function getFuelItem()
    {
        $this->db->set_dbprefix('');
        $q = $this->db->order_by('item_name','ASC')->get_where('store_item', array('status' => 1,
        'item_sub_type'=>'OIL'));
        $this->db->set_dbprefix('tbl_');
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {

            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }

public function isExistProduct($q)
    {
        if (!empty($q)) {
            $this->db->set_dbprefix('');
            $this->db->select("store_item.uom, sum(qty) as qty");
            $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
            $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id');
            $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'right');
            $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.item_id= $q");
            $this->db->group_by('store_item.item_id');
            $q1 = $this->db->get();
            $this->db->set_dbprefix('tbl_');

            if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $q1->result_array();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

## JavaScript & View

```
$(document).on("change", "#item", function () {
            $.ajax({
                'url': '<?=site_url("fuel/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),

                'method': 'GET',
                'success': function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (jData.status == true) {

                        $('#avqty').text(jData.data[0].qty + " " + jData.data[0].uom);

                    }

                },
                'error': function () {

                }
            });
        });

<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select Fuel</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control1" name="item" id="item">
                                        <option value="">Select Fuel</option>
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($fuelItem as $row) {
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $row->item_id ?>"><?= $row->item_name ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <p id="avqty"></p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="avqty" id="avqty">
                                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control1" name="qty" id="qty"
                                           value="<?= set_value('qty') ?>"
                                           placeholder="Quantity...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

## Desired Result

Want to fire the controller message "Issuing Quantity should be less than the available balance" after selecting a fuel item from the list and entering issuing quantity on the "Quantity" cage if issuing quantity is greater than the available balance..

## Output

Code hasn't any error. But not fired the disired message and didn't control the quantity as per desired result.

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: You call the **isExistProduct** method in javascript which is in the model, try calling it in the controller. add method in controller with same name, and call the method model

Comment: @
Salz. Yes. did as you suggested. But not changed the output.